# In Python how to unpack the sublists in the nested list while printing

Tags: python

consider a list l=[1,2,3,4,5].
if we want to unpack the list and also to print, we use * operator to unpack

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(*l,sep="\n")
```

output:
1
2
3
4
5
It is in case of single simple list.
If I have nested list and want to unpack all the sublists like above☝.
consider a sublist sl=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
If I put ** in the print satement it throws an error message.

```
 sl=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
 print(**sl,sep="\n")
```

It doesn't work. 
I want the output as
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

**Is there any chance to unpack the sublists of nested list without loops**

Comment: just run it in a for loop and append every item into an another list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @GhostOps Yes we can use for loop to iterate through the each element in the sublist. But I don't want to use loops. Is there any chance to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) like below:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sl=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> print(*(chain.from_iterable(sl)),sep="\n")
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: I checked this code and it works well. Could you please explain what is going on in print statement

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the list and then unpack it.

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(*[elt for sl in l for elt in sl])
```

Comment: I can't the understand the  code inside in a print statement. Could you please explain  it.

Comment: Its nested list comprehension. 

`sl` is each sublist of `l` and `elt` is each element of each sublist. So `[elt for sl in l for elt in sl]` becomes `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: Thanks. It's simple

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you require you could do this:

```
sl=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print('\n'.join([str(x) for y in sl for x in y]))
```